# Loop through object from web service and get the values in c#

Tags: c#, web-services

I have the following class object returning from webmethod to my codebehind

```
  public class Status_api_call
        {
            public bool Success { get; set; }
            public object obj { get; set; }
            public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        }
```

I have used  `[XmlInclude(typeof(base_api.Status_api_call))]` above my webmethod.

Once I get the `Status_api_call` object to my code behind as a return object, I need to get the values of `Success`, `obj`  and the `ErrorMessage`.

How can i do this ?

Comment: `instanceOfStatusApiCall.Success`?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy  
 
The class Status_api_call is used from webmethod as a return value. When I consume the webservice, I get the object with the values returned from webmethod. I do not have the Status_api_call class in the place where i consume the web service. I just have the object. I could see .GetType() for this object. Can i get the values with that ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the problem is, but if you call your web service and get back the result, like:

```
 var result = myService.GetData();
```

then you can access the properties like:

```
 var success = result.Success;
```

Assuming you generated a proxy. If not, you have to extend your answer to be more complete on how you call the web service.

Comment: I have added the URL as web reference. And in the code behind, I have instantiated the class and called the webmethod. Which returns me the class above as object. I do not have proxy class

Comment: well, then you can access the properties as described as it's a strongly typed object.